# ¿Como obtener un mapa en blanco sin etiquetas de los negocios con la api de google maps para android studio?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, studio

Este es el método donde invoco el mapa y lo ubico en las coordenas que deseo, el metodo de dibujargeorefrencia es para añadir los marcadores(marker) y quisiera que me apareciera el mapa dibujado pero sin las etiquetas de los negocios que ya vienen por default y solo tener mis marcadores.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapa = googleMap;
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(19.707611075950084, -101.1888419188767);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15);
    mapa.moveCamera(update);
    if (mapa != null) {
       dibujarGeoReferencias();

        mapa.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                String spos = ((String) marker.getTag());

                int pos = Integer.parseInt(spos);

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Actividad_despliegue.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                Nodo nod = (Nodo) Datos.nodoList.get(pos);
                b.putString("nombre", nod.getNombre());
                b.putString("Sintomas",nod.getSintomas());
                b.putString("Direccion",nod.getDireccion());
                b.putInt("edad", nod.getEdad());
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que esto es unicamente posible usando la vista de satellite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realizandolo de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapa = googleMap;
    ...
    ...
    mapa.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE); 
}
```